# Why is Michael Mann's The Keep currently unavailable?

Tags: the-keep

I've heard that Michael Mann doesn't like his own version of the atmospheric *Nazi-Zombie-alien* movie *The Keep* and I know the the original story author, F Paul Wilson, really hated it. It also [isn't very well rated in IMDB](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0085780/).

I liked it, though I saw it a long time ago. Is it really that bad? Is there any clear evidence about who is blocking it from being on DVD?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Paramount Studios had intended to release *The Keep* on DVD in 2004, but this would have been the (frankly incomprehensible) version, edited down to 96 minutes from Mann's original 180 minute version, and the release was shelved for no apparent reason.

The edited version seen in theaters and on VHS is indeed pretty poor and doesn't make a whole lot of sense, due, I would think, to being only half a film!

There appears to be no clear evidence over who is blocking the film, and I am not convinced that Mann has enough power to do so, but efforts have been underway for a while now to get a full, director's cut, release made. You can follow these efforts on this fan-run site [here](http://www.the-keep.ath.cx/default_en.htm) and sign the petition [here](http://keepfilm.com/). This site does include a fascinating [interview with Mann](http://www.the-keep.ath.cx/default_en.htm) from 1983.

Incidently, a [graphic novel](https://shop.idwpublishing.com/comics/graphic-novels/the-keep-tpb.html) was produced, which F Paul Wilson adapted himself.

Comment: Has the long version ever been released?

Comment: Not that I am aware of.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the reason behind The Keep not being released is because neither Virgin records or Tangerine Dream, which performed the music for The Keep, wants to release what they feel is their rights to the music.  Since neither party wants to let go of the music (I tend to side with Tangerine Dream in this case), the movie will sit in limbo until the issue is resolved.  You might find supporting information about this on Tangerine Dream's website but I cannot remember the exact citation or link.

I think it will come down to a legal decision on who owns the rights to the music before we get to see The Keep released.  I hope a decision comes soon because the movie and the music is one of those rare combinations where the music and the story match perfectly.