# Why is Benji currently unavailable?

Tags: distribution

In going through a series of classic movies with my kids we came to the 1974 Benji, about a lovable stray dog that rescues some kidnapped children.

I live in Pennsylvania, USA, and cannot watch it. I'd pay for it, but it's unavailable on any streaming service I've been able to find. I bought The Benji Collection, in Blu-Ray, DVD and digital code, and found that my (admittedly dusty) PS3 was unable to read either disc. To be sure, it happily reads my Blu-Ray collection of the BBC Planet Earth series.

The digital code led me to create an account on moviespree.com, which accepted the code and then told me the movie was unavailable.

I'm basically familiar with the idea that some films are unavailable due to regional controls. But Benji is an American film, and I'm in the USA.

So, I'm hoping someone on this site understands the industry well enough to explain why Benji, an inoffensive, American film, is so difficult to get to watch.

Comment: Shopping questions are off-topic. This film is trivially easy to find in a format that will play on a player in the US

Comment: I did not ask how to buy or find the film. I only laid how how I had tried to in order to provide context for the question. I used https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/872 and https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/102364 as basic guidance to the idea that it was OK to ask to understand why a title would be unavailable. Neither of those has been flagged, and both seem to be well enough received.

Comment: @Valorum - yes previous media releases of the movie are available on eBay, Amazon etc. However it's hard to conclude much about current license availability from that. The last media release that I can find was produced in 2020, indicating that there was at least some interest in what was then a 46 year old movie. However while all three of the Benji sequels are available for streaming, the much more popular original (based on gross revenue) is conspicuously absent, which indicates that something may be going on with the copyright.

Comment: If it's, as it sounds, a technical problem, earlier releases might have a different [video codec](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Video_codec) (and [more to read](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DVD-Video)). Could be worth a try and dig deeper...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's an interesting question because there does seem to be something going on currently with the license for the original Benji movie, which in its day was a very popular movie, as was the dog who starred in it, as I will detail below for those who are interested in the film. Although it's hard to reliably gauge current interest in older films, it can be noted that the sequels to the original are available for streaming even though the more popular original film currently isn't.

You actually bring up three separate facets, the lack of available streaming for *Benji* (1974), problems with your disc media, and problems with your digital copy. I will discuss possible reasons for this, but first for anyone interested here is some info on the (at the time) popularity of the film, popular enough that there should be some carryover to present day.

It can be noted that *Benji* (1974) was a "Higgins" film. Higgins in some ways followed in the footsteps of Pal, a dog who appeared in a series of Lassie films in the 1940's, and his offspring Lassie Junior (yes both were male) who appeared in the first several seasons of the Lassie TV series. Higgins had a pretty remarkable 14-year career, and first came to national attention as the family dog in the popular 1960's TV series *Petticoat Junction* for six seasons, and was also seen each week in the iconic closing credits as Higgins runs behind the Cannonball steam train.

[image: Petticoat Junction cast]

Original Petticoat Junction cast: Linda Kaye, Edgar Buchanan, Higgins, Bea Benaderet, Jeannine Riley, Pat Woodell

Higgins' main interaction on the show was with Uncle Joe, played by Edgar Buchanan, who reportedly became very fond of Higgins.

[image: Edgar Buchanan and Higgins]
Higgins and Edgar Buchanan

Higgins by all accounts was a remarkable dog. I remember a story by a Petticoat Junction actor where Higgins had to pick up some keys, carry them across the room, jump up onto a desk and deposit the keys in a certain spot, then jump off the desk and do one other piece of business that I don't remember now what it was. And he did it all in one take. In the [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Higgins_(dog)#Career) article on Higgins it says:

> Higgins was able to convey a broad range of emotions through his facial expressions. (owner and trainer Frank Inn) who trained thousands of animals of many species during his lifetime, told reporters that Higgins was the smartest dog he had ever worked with and noted that during his prime years in television, he learned one new trick or routine per week and retained these routines from year to year, making it possible for him to take on increasingly varied and complex roles.

At age 16 Higgins, who had been found as a puppy at an animal shelter by Inn, was at the end of his career, and *Benji* was his last film.

[image: Benji poster]

*Benji* (1974) movie poster

It can be noted that *Benji* was also the last film for Edgar Buchanan, and also for Frances Bavier who played Aunt Bee on *The Andy Griffith Show*. The role of Benji was taken over by other dogs in subsequent films.

*Benji* was a very popular sleeper hit in 1974, grossing $45 million on a budget of $500,000 ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Benji_(1974_film))). It was an independent film produced by Mulberry Square Productions. As for why it is not currently available on streaming services, it's possible that the current rights owner simply is not currently interested in making it available, which happens sometimes when movie rights are transferred, for example through buyouts or as part of an inheritance. Or there could be some type of current legal hangup with the rights. Or the owner thinks that it is worth more than streaming services are willing to pay. These are just some of the possibilities, without inside knowledge or public statements by those involved there is no way to know what the current issue is. In theory it could simply be a lack of demand, but considering the original popularity of the film, and the fact that 1943's *Lassie Come Home* is available for streaming, I would guess that it's more likely one of these type of reasons.

Previous media releases of the movie are available on eBay, Amazon etc., however it's hard to conclude much about current license availability from that. The last media release that I can find was produced in 2020, indicating that there was at least some interest in what was then a 46 year old movie. However while all three of the *Benji* sequels (also produced by Mulberry Square) are available for streaming, the much more popular original (based on gross revenue) is conspicuously absent, which indicates that something may be going on with the copyright. It's possible that any attempted new release of *Benji* on media would run into a license issue if it's currently not available.

As for your Blu-ray and DVD issues, it can be noted that media releases of *Benji* have not been on the major labels, presumably since it was an independent production. Looking at the various DVD's available they seem to all be produced by lesser known labels like Cinedigm and Camp Brand. I am guessing that your Blu-ray/DVD/Digital set is the one produced by Mill Creek in 2019. Possibly the digital copy has expired, although based on your experience where it was accepted but then listed as not available, it could be because of the apparent rights issue.

Not to disparage those media labels, but it's possible that the disc production quality is not the same as a major label like Sony or WB. Since your Blu-ray player sounds like it is older, it's possible that the alignment isn't perfect anymore, which can cause a player to not play discs that themselves are not aligned correctly or have other imperfections. You might try playing the discs on a friend's player to see if this is the case.

Comment: I guess the downvotes to my answer means "I don't like this" or "I don't find this  interesting" or "I think this is stupid". All of which are valid opinions which anyone is entitled to, however it's not really the purpose of downvotes which is supposed to mean that it was a wrong or inaccurate answer or irrelevant to the question. In this case I provided information on why the movie would be expected to have at least some demand based on the popularity of the "actor" and the success of the film. As well as  possible reasons why it's not currently streamed, and the media problems encountered.

Comment: I downvoted because 90% of this answer is totally irrelevant to the question at hand. The other 10% is unsourced guesswork.

Comment: @Valorum - understood and a valid opinion for someone who has less interest in the topic than the OP or others. By topic I mean this particular movie. The narrower topic of what causes some films with at least some level of popularity to not be available would have a narrower answer. As for quesswork, valid from a viewpoint where only fully vetted, authoritative answers should ever be given. But then a lot of questions which require inside knowledge would remain void of any answers. If someone with specific topic knowledge comes along they will get more upvotes, so it all takes care of itself.

Comment: If it's, as it sounds, a technical problem, earlier releases might have a different [video codec](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Video_codec) (and [more to read](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DVD-Video)). Could be worth a try and dig deeper...